# How to locate the whole South Africa map on leaflet

Tags: javascript, dc.leaflet.js

I am trying to Display South Africa map only on leaflet.js and when i run my application it keeps on displaying just a small area instead of the whole country

```html
    var map = L.map('map').setView([-30.0000, 25.0000], 12);

        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            maxZoom: 18
            //L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/e7b61e61295a44a5b319ca0bd3150890/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            //    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery Â© <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',

        }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your initialization code, it seems that the 2nd parameter is the default zoom level:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([-30.0000, 25.0000], 12);
```

Change the 12 to a 4 to show the entire continent.

Comment: That's good to hear. Could you select my answer?

Comment: By just clicking on the Tick ?

Comment: Yes. and you already did it. Thanks. Let me know if you have further questions.